# backbone.js set model attribute inner field

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to set an attribute of a backbone.js model, but only an inner field rather than the entire field.

Example code might be:

```
model.set('user.avatar', 'img')
```

Anything I can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could simply make a copy of the object, set the attribute, and then re-set it on the original model:

```
var userAttributes = model.get("user");
userAttributes.avatar = "img";
model.set("user", userAttributes)
```

Or add a function to set parts of the user on the model from an object:

```
model = Backbone.Model.extend({
...
setUser: function(attributes){
    var user = this.get("user") || {};
    _.extend(user, attributes);
    this.set({user:user});
},
...
```

Then pass in attributes like so: `model.setUser({avatar: "img"});`

Comment: instead of the each, wouldn't the extend of underscore be more useful? other than that still a good solution!